# Выборка ссылок YouTube

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Здравствуйте! Имеется текст. Как из него можно выбрать ссылки видеороликов YouTube?
Например, 
$text = "Это крутое видео на YouTube: [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cfYDc-yafbM";](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cfYDc-yafbM)

Answer (score 4):

С помощью регулярного выражения, например: ^http:\/\/(?:www.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=[^?]*v=\w+)(?:[^\s?]+)?$

Answer (score -3):

Регулярным выражением.
Составьте маску, по которой будете определять, с ютуба это видео или нет.